# List index out of range error, but value is there?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the 5th value stored inside 'col_1'. When I go to print the 5th value, or use it, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/test_files/test_two.py", line 99, in <module>
print(col_1[5])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, if I try values 1,4 it's completely fine? I have code that places entries into these lists:

```
def do_query():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('test_db.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT PRODUCT,BIN,SIZE,COLOR FROM TESTER_6 ORDER BY CheckNum")
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print(records)

    for(Product,Bin,Size,Color) in records:
        col_1.append(Product)
        col_2.append(Bin)
        col_4.append(Size)
        col_3.append(Color)

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

When I print 'records', there is a 5th entry. Somehow it's not getting into the list during the for loop.

Why am I having this issue?

Comment: Can't tell for sure if this is the mistake you are making, but are you aware that lists are 0-indexed in Python? The first element is at `list[0]` and the fifth element at `list[4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most languages, Python indices start at 0.

If you have five elements in a list, calling `col_1[5]` will give an `IndexError`. Rather, the fifth element in the list is `col_1[4]`.

```
col_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
index:    0    1    2    3    4
```

So:

```
>>> col_1[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> col_1[4]
'e'
>>> col_1[0]
'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

Lists in Python, as with most languages, are 0-based. So even if there are 5 elements, there is no `element[5]`. If you started with 1, your missing element is actually index `0`

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```